# C++ User enters x amount of inputs than sum them

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to enter how many integers they would like to sum then asks them to input those integers and sum them.

```
int main() {

  char choice;

  do {
    int input, sum, num1, num2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "How many integer values would you like to sum? ";
    cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
      cout << "Enter integer ";
      cin >> num1;
    }
    sum = num1;

    cout << "Do you want to go again (y/n)? ";
    cin >> choice;

  } while (choice == 'y');

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve with my program:

```
How many numbers are you going to enter? 5
Enter data: -5
Enter data: 2
Enter data: 3
Enter data: 6
Enter data: 0
The sum is 6
```

Comment: Set sum to 0 at the start of the outer loop then on the inner loop do sum += num1 after you have read num1 from the user, then output the sum

Comment: Thank you so much I couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the value of input integers into sum every time in the for loop
using `sum += num` or `sum = sum + num` both works in the same way.

```
char choice;

do {
    int input, sum, num;
    
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << "How many integer values would you like to sum? ";
    cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        cout << "Enter integer "; 
        cin >> num;
        sum += num; 
    }
    

    cout << "Do you want to go again (y/n)? ";
    cin >> choice;

} while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

cout << endl;
  
return 0;
}
```